# Is there a way to put interactive matplotlib graphs in django webpages?

Tags: python, django, matplotlib

I want to make an interactive plot, so that clicking on a position on the plot, shifts the plot to the position.

I have implemented it in matplotlib or PyQt. But I don't know how to make interactive matplotlib graphs in webpages (particularly django).

Is there any way to detect click locations on matplotlib plots which are shown in a browser?

Thank you